# dojo/mobile orientation change on ios don't resize as expected

Tags: ios, mobile, dojo, resize, orientation

I have been experiencing some issues on IOS version of my mobile app, that each time I rotate the device, the screen doesn't resize as expected, it stuck on previous orientation or size.
I have made a research and found that this bug existed on previous versions of dojo. And that also exist solutions and patches.
But I am using a newer version and it still happening like those previous cases.
Here are the links of those cases:

```
bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16658
bugs.dojotoolkit.../17539
bugs.dojotoolkit.../16490
```

I am using Dojo 1.9.3  And some of those solutions were already patched.
Can anyone help me on this, and/or if you know if exists a way to force a resize()?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we listen for the even and run a resize

```
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    dojox.mobile.resizeAll();
}, false);
```